# LaTeX doesn't show negative sign in exponent

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

Writing the code

```
The weight decay was set to $1 \times {10^{−4}}$ for Model 8 and $5\times 10^{−4}$.
```

the negative sign is missing.

[image]

And these are the packages I'm using

```
\usepackage{jmlr2e}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
% Definitions of handy macros can go here
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{underscore}
\restylefloat{table}
\newcommand{\dataset}{{\cal D}}
\newcommand{\fracpartial}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial  #2}}
```

Comment: Please give a minimal working sample.

Comment: By the way, the `\cal` command has been deprecated for 25 years. It should be `\mathcal{D}` rather than `{\cal D}`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem occurs because the symbol `−` that's used in both exponents is not a "normal" dash symbol, `-`. Instead, it is the Unicode symbol `U+2212`, the "math minus" symbol. (Did you maybe copy and paste the input from some other source?)

Here are three remedies:

- Switch to either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX and load either the `fontspec` package or the `unicode-math` package (which loads `fontspec` automatically).
- If you need to use pdfLaTeX, add the following instructions to your preamble:

  ```
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{-}
  ```
- Finally, consider simply replacing all instances of `−` with `-`. (That's what's done in the code below.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section*{Your code}
The weight decay was set to $1 \times {10^{−4}}$ for Model 8 and $5 
\times 10^{−4}$.

\bigskip

\section*{Correct code}
The weight decay was set to $1 \times {10^{-4}}$ for Model 8 and $5 
\times 10^{-4}$.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've taken the liberty of augmenting your answer a bit. :-)

Comment: @Mico It's perfect to me. Thank you for improving my answer with your original contribution, I really appreciate that. `;-)`

Comment: Just to be fussy: I wouldn't write that `-` is a normal _dash_: this might be confusing as it recalls the en and the em dash. The correct name, I believe, is _hyphen_.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed your codes as follows:

```
The weight decay was set to $1 \times {10^{-4}}$ for Model 8 and $5\times 10^{-4}$.
```

And the following is the PDF style.

[image]

The reason that why your `−` can't be complied may be that you type it not in English typewriting. Please make sure you are under English typewriting when you type codes in math environment.

Comment: I wouldn't emphasize the "English" aspect. The exact same problem is going to occur if the document is in French, German, Italian, ...

Comment: Hopefully needless to say, the preceding comment was not supposed to slight users of Spanish, Portuguese, Norwegian, Swedish, Finnish, Polish, etc, etc, etc.

Answer (score 2):

shorter and correct with use `siunitx` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
The weight decay was set to \num{1e-4} for Model 8 and \num{5e-4}.
\end{document}
```

[image]